# Git having different branches push to different remote repos

Tags: git, github

I'm using git on github.com to develop a project I'm working on.

I have a private repo on github.com, let's call it WORKING, on which I push my daily commits, create lots of branches. Each commit is full of crappy messages and all sort of imprecations.

All I wanted to do is, if possible, setup a new PUBLIC repo on github, create a new local branch, call it CLEAN, on which I would like to merge WORKING/master to get rid of all the imprecation in the branch history and then push this new branch to my new remote public repository.

Is this possible?

Maybe it would be easier to manually move the files to my new created repo and then push them, but it would be great if git could allow me to do so.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is possible.

Just add another remote for your second repository.

- Use `git remote -v` to list your current remotes. (There is probably only one remote `origin`).
- Now add a new remote with `git remote add clean $URL`.
- Afterwards you can push to that repository using `git push clean`.

Be aware that a merge will preserve all the crappy commits of the involved branches. Hence, a merge is not a good way to get rid of them.

Usually you have those lots of branches with all the crappy commits only as local branches in you own repository. Then you can clean them up using `git rebase -i` and once the look fine you push them.

Comment: I'm using this remote private repo since I want to have a backup of the work :). So if I merge, let's say MASTER (which have the crappy commits) to NEW_BRANCH_FOR_ALL_THE_PEOPLE all the crap remain in the history, right?

Comment: Exactly. git will generally never forget any commits you did. You need something like `git rebase -i` to change history explicitly. To see it yourself, use `gitk` after the merge.

Comment: Are there any options like "merge all the commits as if it was a single commit"?

Comment: Have a look at `git help merge`. You probably want the `--squash` option.